# Many CSVs to list, optimize

Tags: python, performance, csv

I have a Python3 script (running on Python 3.5.2) which reads 110 CSV files (tab delimited) into a list. The largest file is 20 MB and the list ends up looking like this:

```
[
    [line1],
    [line2],
    [line2021756],
    etc.
]
```

Right now the process takes about 32 seconds to complete:

```
python3 -m cProfile -s time script.py

10 files found
2021756 non-unique lines found.

9600828 function calls (9600673 primitive calls) in 32.900 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   30.451   30.451   32.890   32.890 script.py:81(main)
  7419324    1.945    0.000    1.945    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
  2021994    0.189    0.000    0.189    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
    76528    0.164    0.000    0.164    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.utf_8_decode}
    76528    0.130    0.000    0.294    0.000 codecs.py:318(decode)
      110    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method io.open}
        5    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.FileIO' objects}
        3    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
        5    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method posix.listdir}
      110    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method _csv.reader}
       48    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1215(find_spec)
      111    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {built-in method posix.lstat}
      332    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 posixpath.py:71(join)
```

... and I would like to know if there is **a way to significantly reduce that time?**. It seems `startswith` and `append` are the main bottlenecks.

**script.py**

```
# Find CSV files.
files_found = glob.glob('{0}dir_*_name/{1}'.format(input_dir,file_of_interest))
len_files_found = len(files_found)
if len_files_found == 0:
    print_message('Error: zero {0} files found'.format(file_of_interest), True)
print_message('{0} files found'.format(len_files_found), False)

# Read each file into files_found_lines.
# files_found_lines will look like [[line1],[line2],[line3],...]
files_found_lines = []
for file in files_found:
    try:
        # Open file for reading text.
        with open(file, 'rt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
            for row in reader:
                # Keep lines starting with BLAH.
                if row[0].startswith('BLAH'):
                    # Get first 9 columns.
                    files_found_lines.append(row[0:9])
    except Exception as error:
        print_message('Error: {0}'.format(error), True)
```

It's possible I may end up reading each CSV file into its own list instead of one big list like above, so just FYI.

Comment: I suggest that you tell us more about what the data look like, and what you intend to do with it once you have read it.

Comment: It may be prudent to look at [other ways of reading CSVs in python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file). For example, pandas read_csv function is much than csv reader

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want lines starting with BLAH, filter the lines before parsing the CSV. I think the profiler is misleading you by attributing the time spent parsing CSV to the line `for row in reader` in your code.

```
with open(file, 'rt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    filtered = (line for line in f if line.startswith('BLAH'))
    reader = csv.reader(filtered, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        files_found_lines.append(row[0:9])
```